# Make footer bar disappear on scrolling in a Delphi / Firemonkey app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a simple Delphi / Firemonkey app that has a lot of data within a TListView. To maximize the available space on screen, I want to make the footer bar disappear with animation if the user scrolls down. Just the same way the LinkedIn app does (at least on Android) for example. Is there an easy way to get there? Some mechanism that is integrated in then Firemonkey framework (like TMultiView)?

I'm using Delphi 11.2.

Thank you!

Comment: Which Delphi version? Please provide a [mre] and include both `.pas` and `.fmx` files. I have no idea how the "LinkedIn" app, that you mention, works. Please do some effort in explaining what you need, without referring to other applications. When you initially started your project, which template did you select? Maybe "Header/Footer with Navigation", or ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FireMonkey you can achieve this quite easily by using Animations like [TFloatAnimation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Ani.TFloatAnimation) which you can attach to any visual FMX component.

For instance if your **footer bar** is a [StatusBar](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TStatusBar) this is  how you will done it:

1. In Form design select your status bar component
2. Find `TFloatAnimation` component in your component palette and double click on it. This will add Float Animation to the status bar. If done correctly Float Animation will be shown as child component of your status bar.
3. Change the `PropertyName` property of the added Float Animation to point to `StatusBar.Size.Height` property. This tells the Float Animation that it will be updating Status bars height property.
4. Now write two new procedures which you can then call to fire the prepared animation when needed.

The procedures would look something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.HideStatusBar;
begin
  //Store initial height of the status bar as start value so we can use it later
  //for restoring status bar to initial size
  FloatAnimation2.StartValue := StatusBar1.Height;
  FloatAnimation2.StopValue := 0;
  //Set inverste property to false.
  FloatAnimation2.Inverse := False;
  //Start the animation
  FloatAnimation2.Start;
end;

procedure TForm2.ShowStatusBar;
begin
  //In order to reverse animation we need to set Inverse property to True
  //We don't store any StartValue or StopValue since we have done that already
  //when we decided to hide the status bar
  FloatAnimation2.Inverse := True;
  //Start the reverse animation
  FloatAnimation2.Start;
end;
```

The reason why I store initial height of the status bar within HideStatsBar procedure instead of setting it at design time is to allow scenarios where you may allow your users to change the size of the said status bar.

NOTE: If your **footer bar** is a panel with Bottom alignment be aware that animating panel breaks the alignment and other components don't update their size properly as they should. I haven't figured out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you SilverWarior ! This was exactly what I was searching for. A solution that is framework-integrated. The only caveat is, that my footer is a TPanel containing images as buttons and some focus indicator rectangles :-( Now, I have to check the events in my TListView, either OnGesture or OnScrollView will do it. I'm I'm using Delphi 11.2 but that solution seems to be version agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of SilverWarior, I got it finally working perfect just for my needs. To apply to Tom Brunberg's questions I will provide a full solution here including SilverWarior's slightly modified code of course.

I'm using the "HeaderFooter Template" of Delphi 11.2 but had to change the footer TToolbar to a bottom-aligned TPanel. It did not work with a TToolbar on Android. I placed the TListview in the middle of the form.

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
// just add some testing data
ListView1.BeginUpdate;

for var iCnt := 0 to 4711 do
    ListView1.Items.Add.Text:='ListView Item  ' + iCnt.ToString;

ListView1.EndUpdate;

FScrollPos:=0;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
var iNewPos:=ListView1.ScrollViewPos;

if FScrollPos > iNewPos then
   begin
   HeaderLabel.Text:='OnScroll Up';
   Self.ShowStatusBar;
   end
else
   begin
   HeaderLabel.Text:='OnScroll Down';
   Self.HideStatusBar;
   end;

FScrollPos:=iNewPos
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.HideStatusBar;
begin
// hiding the footer if height is already zero makes the footer simply do
// nothing on Android (but works in Win64)
if Footer.Height < 2 then
   Exit;

// store initial height of the status bar as start value so we can use it later
// for restoring status bar to initial size
FloatAnimation1.StartValue := Footer.Height;
FloatAnimation1.StopValue := 0;

// start the animation
FloatAnimation1.Start;

// just for debugging
HeaderLabel.Text:=HeaderLabel.Text +  ' AnimHideStart';
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.ShowStatusBar;
begin
// showing the footer if already visible makes it simply do nothing (but works in Win64)
if Footer.Height > 40 then
   Exit;

// using the (far more elegant) .Invers machanism did not work
FloatAnimation1.StartValue := 0;
FloatAnimation1.StopValue := 48;

// start the animation
FloatAnimation1.Start;

// just for debugging
HeaderLabel.Text:=HeaderLabel.Text +  ' AnimShowStart';
end;
```

This minimal example code placed within the form works on Windows 11 x64 and x86 and on my Android 13 device. Would be interesting on an iOS device of course.